# How does JavaScript emulate the behavior of `private` members?

Tags: javascript, oop, private

> REF: https://github.com/aleen42/PersonalWiki/blob/docs/qa/how_does_js_emulate_private_members.md

As we all know, the proposal of `private` instance fields in classes has been pushed towards stage 4 since ES2022. It means that we can define private members inside classes like other OOP languages, which are limited to access outside a class in user code.

How does JavaScript emulate such behaviour?

Comment: Why emulate something when it's part of the language?

Comment: @Andreas The original implementation of the `class` syntax was designed simply as a way to simplify writing constructors. Under the hood, the class syntax did not add anything new. It was still the old `ConstructorFunction.prototype = example_object` system. It was always intended for the `class` syntax to not add any new feature to existing javascript runtime. So if we now add `private` fields to the class syntax what does it look like in the old prototypal syntax?

Comment: @Andreas If on the other hand this new `private` field proposal introduces a new object type in javascript then it is a HUGE change to the language, not just a simple new feature. If that is the case the answer to this question should explain this

Comment: It's a [(stage 4) proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/), so the _"how it will/can be done"_ is already available (and the "answer" below of OP is a copy of an analogy of that proposal).

Comment: So the question should be: "How does JavaScript implement `private` members?"

Answer (score -1):

Use [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap). For why? The [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap#emulating_private_members) has given us the answer:

- Compared to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), a `WeakMap` does not hold strong references to the object used as the key, so the metadata shares the same lifetime as the object itself, avoiding memory leaks.
- Compared to using non-enumerable and/or [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) properties, a `WeakMap` is external to the object and there is no way for user code to retrieve the metadata through reflective methods like [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols).

  ```js
  class A {
      constructor() {
          this[Symbol('#private')] = 'unreachable value?';
      }
  }

  // we can access it actually:
  const a = new A();
  a[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(a)[0]]; // => "unreachable value?"
  ```
- Compared to a closure, the same `WeakMap` can be reused for all instances created from a constructor, making it more memory-efficient, and allowing different instances of the same class to read the private members of each other.

The detailed implementation when the runtime environment does not support the proposal:

```js
const A = (function () {
    // use a closure to ensure that the weak map cannot be accessed outside the class A
    const privates = new WeakMap();
    return class {
        constructor() {
            privates.set(this, {['#private'] : 'unreachable value?'});
        }
        getPrivateValue() {
            return privates.get(this)['#private'];
        }
    }
})();

const a = new A();
// the private member can only be accessed via an exposed method
a.getPrivateValue(); // => "unreachable value?"
```

Comment: How does this answer OPs question: _"How does JavaScript emulate such behaviour?"_?